# Cannot find roles database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently working on a website in ASP.NET wherein a login system is required. However upon erroneously assuming the connection string for the roles database was the same as the connection string for my Microsoft SQL database, I realised that I did not know where the roles database was. I ran a search through my computer for something resembling a roles database (searching for both roles and .mdf) and found nothing that I could identify as this. Do you know what mistakes I am making here? Do I have to specifically create this roles database? Thus far my web.config code reads as (without personally identifying connection strings at the top):

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <roleManager  enabled="true" defaultProvider="providerForLogin">
      <providers>
        <add name="providerForLogin" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" applicationName="WebSite4" connectionStringName="ConnectionString" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Comment: It would be weird if they were *different* databases. From the looks of things, you are using the standard ASP.NET providers...so take a step back. What are you trying to do? If you do want to go down the route of using the ASP.NET Membership provider..... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

ASP.Net membership doesn't create a separate database, if you specify same database connection string.

The way you are doing is correct which keeps Users, Role, Membership table in same database where your tables exist.

FYI: If your application is new, please use [Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) which is a replacement for old ASP.Net Membership (the one you are currently using)

Comment: Doing something like this I end up with the error: "Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.". I am assuming this is because the database has not been initialised or something like that? Is this something to do with running aspnet_regsql.exe?

Comment: Using aspnet_regsql.exe to create membership tables are outdated. Please use univeral providers (see my answer) which uses NuGet.

Answer (score 1):

There is an executable file named `aspnet_regsql.exe` that you need to run for the membership schema to get created. Follow [this tutorial](http://www.shiningstar.net/ASPNet_Articles/SqlMembershipProvider.aspx)

However, and like @Win said, this is an old one. Use [Universal Providers](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/stronger-password-hashing-net) if you are developing with VS2012.